# Oracle ADF 11.1.1.4 blind query triggered

Tags: oracle, session-timeout, oracle-adf

I am working/maintaining an application built on Oracle ADF 11.1.1.4 version migrated from 10g during developement phase itself. We are using BC4j to talk to Oracle 10g database. The application is very heavily data centric and so there are chances that the query triggered through GUI may be have bad plan based on the search criteria entered by the user. Most of the places we have marked few fields mandatory to search on where potentially we see a bad query to be formed.

Issue: Currently in production user open muliple tabs for different screens, one of which is a screen where we have made it mandatory to enter few search values before searching/Querying the data. In the corresponding view criteria of that View Object we have marked those fields as selective required. But somehow we see a blind query triggered even when user hasn't clicked on search button on that page
It seems to comeup when the session expires on one of the pages opened and user clicks the OK.  button

I am not sure is the framework triggereing some blind query when the page expires or else. There are many listeners on the page, but I am not sure why session timeeout can cause it.THe query is the same as that in the corresponding VO where we have maked few fields as selectively required. The long running query causes stuck thread on Weblogic server causing it to crash eventually after sometime.

Kindly anybody please advise if there has been an Oracle bug reported or any solution. We are seeing this on couple of pages where view criteria has few fields marked as selectively required.

Thanks

@Edit: The pages either jspx or page fragments jsff

Answer (score 0):

You might be running into an effect as described here http://andrejusb.blogspot.ca/2012/08/adf-bc-passivationactivation-and-sql.html?m=1 
You can try the technique I showed here https://tompeez.wordpress.com/2012/03/18/jdeveloper-preventing-return-of-large-row-sets-on-page-load-of-vo-using-bind-variable/ to prevent executing of queues on first load.

Comment: Hi Timo, Thanks for prompt reply. Currently I have multpile screens in my application so not sure where should I create the first unbounded task flow as the page I am having issue on isn't the first screen the app starts with. Currently adfc-config.xml is configured having a different task flow.

Comment: initialAdf refreshes each bounded task follow when it enters it the first time or after activation. So you have to prevent initial queries without parameters for each of them.